# Comparing questionnaires with actual observations: is it worth it?

Tags: probability, survey, observational-study

First of 2 part query: I have observed a 100 Drs and recorded the number of times they touch surfaces while in a room:

$$
\begin{array}{l|c|c|c|c}
Dr\text{ number}&Bed&Table&Chair&Door\\
Dr 1&3&2&2&1\\
Dr 2&4&1&0&1\\
\vdots&\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\
Dr 100& 2&3&1&1
\end{array}
$$
I would like to calculate the probability of him touching the Table for example. Would it be:?
$$
\begin{array}{l|c|c|c|c|c}
&Bed&Table&Chair&Door&\text{Total}\\
\text{Average contacts}&3&2&1&1&\text{7}\\
P(surface)&3/7&2/7&1/7&1/7&1
\end{array}
$$
This is confusing me but I think a fresh pair of eyes will spot it instantly.

2nd Part: I gave questionnaires out to some doctors who ticked boxes instead of giving contact numbers ie:

$$
\begin{array}{l|c|c|c|c}
Dr\text{ number}&Bed&Table&Chair&Door\\
Dr  &\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark\\
Dr&\checkmark&\checkmark&\times&\checkmark\\
\vdots&\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\
Dr 100& \checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark
\end{array}
$$

What can I deduce from this table of ticks to compare with the table of exact values? Or is it not worth anything?

Please ask for any clarification needed,
Regards

Comment: In order to be most consistent with the question you want answered, should you maybe change your wording from "I would like to calculate the probability of him touching the Table" to "I would like to calculate the fraction of contacts that are with the Table"?

Comment: Ah is this not the same thing?  If not could you say why? Cheers

Comment: What I mean is, with the 2nd wording we divide (the # of contacts with the table) by (the total # of contacts made), whereas with the first, we simply count the fraction of drs. who have touched the table.  E.g., if 92 out of 100 drs. did so, then our best estimate is that the 101st dr. will have a 92% prob. of touching the table.

Comment: Ah I see exactly what you mean! Thank goodness for insight and clear explanation! So imagine that the 101st Dr has just entered the room and I would like to predict his/her next surface contact. Would this be: P(Table)= (the total # of contacts with table)/(total # of contacts made) ?

Comment: Glad it was helpful.  Your calculation is right, assuming of course that the next dr. behaves in accordance with the average dr. from the first 100.

Comment: Do you think anything useful can be deduced from the questionnaire (ie last table)? If you pop your comments into an answer I can give you a thumbs up. Thank you again! :)

Comment: Just going back to your initial wording: "the fraction of contacts that are with the table". Can this not be referred to as a probability also?